# Styling button tooltip

Tags: html, css, tooltip

Is it possible to style the tooltip of a button, created by:

```
<button title="Hi!">Button</button>
```

I would like to change the font family.

Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not possible. The best you could do is ignore the title attribute and use a JavaScript library that builds its own tooltips.

Answer (score 4):

So you can't directly change the styles that the tooltip uses, but there are options for creating custom tooltips.

Custom Tooltips seem to follow a few basic approaches
- JS library
- CSS using nested span attributes
- CSS using custom classes or attributes

I feel like the best approach for a custom tooltip is to use a CSS solution using a `.tooltip` class and `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements

A simple example might look something like this:

HTML

```
<button class="tooltip" data-title="Hi!">Button</button>
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
   position: relative;
}
.tooltip::before {
   background-color: white;
   border: 1px solid #888;
   border-radius: 2px;
   color: #444;
   content: attr(data-title);
   display: none;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   padding: 2px 5px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   left: 5px;
   z-index: 1;
}
.tooltip:hover::before {
   display: block;
}
```

A few other good links:

A good guide: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-step-by-step-guide-to-making-pure-css-tooltips-3d5a3e237346

W3's nested span example: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

A simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/1rbnLbbx/

Animated Tooltips: https://codepen.io/neogomo/pen/BjqJzr

Answer (score 2):

You can use pseudo class to make your custom tooltips.

```css
    button { margin: 10px; }
    button:hover:after { 
        content: "Hi"; 
        font-family: Arial;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 20px;
        height: 1.25rem;   
        background-color: gray;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the tooltip title. But you need to create your own class Instead of TITLE"", see the example here:

See the HTML AND CSS CODE:

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
 font-family: consolas,monospace;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Run then you can see the Tooltip title would be changed.